# how to assign empty value "" using append() in a loop

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm doing the scrape using Selenium and found out that I always miss the value since xpath is not exist in one data. I want to assign empty value to not disturb the index scraped list. any idea how can we assign empty value given the xpath return []?

[image]

this is the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

area = []
areaprice = []

url = 'https://www.rumah.com/properti-dijual/3?beds%5B0%5D=2&freetext=bandung+selatan&minbath=1&minsize=80&property_type=B&property_type_code%5B0%5D=BUNG&unselected=AREA%7CIDJB01011'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url) 
  
time.sleep(5) 

for q in range (13,15):
    
    area_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="listings-container"]/div['+ str(q) +']/div[1]/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]')
    if area_element is not None:
        for x in area_element:
            area.append(x.text)

    areaprice_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="listings-container"]/div['+ str(q) +']/div[1]/div[2]/ul[2]/li[3]')
    if areaprice_element is not None:
        for x in areaprice_element:
            areaprice.append(x.text)
    else:
        areaprice.append(0)
        
[area,areaprice]
```

After revised code with ' '.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply append an empty string as following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

area = []
areaprice = []

url = 'https://www.rumah.com/properti-dijual/3?beds%5B0%5D=2&freetext=bandung+selatan&minbath=1&minsize=80&property_type=B&property_type_code%5B0%5D=BUNG&unselected=AREA%7CIDJB01011'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url) 
  
time.sleep(5) 

for q in range (13,15):
    
    area_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="listings-container"]/div['+ str(q) +']/div[1]/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]')
    if area_element is not None:
        for x in area_element:
            area.append(x.text)
    else:
        area.append("")

    areaprice_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="listings-container"]/div['+ str(q) +']/div[1]/div[2]/ul[2]/li[3]')
    if areaprice_element is not None:
        for x in areaprice_element:
            areaprice.append(x.text)
    else:
        areaprice.append("")
```

In case you need something like a space   there, you can use `' '` instead of `""` so the code will be as following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

area = []
areaprice = []

url = 'https://www.rumah.com/properti-dijual/3?beds%5B0%5D=2&freetext=bandung+selatan&minbath=1&minsize=80&property_type=B&property_type_code%5B0%5D=BUNG&unselected=AREA%7CIDJB01011'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url) 
  
time.sleep(5) 

for q in range (13,15):
    
    area_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="listings-container"]/div['+ str(q) +']/div[1]/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]')
    if area_element is not None:
        for x in area_element:
            area.append(x.text)
    else:
        area.append(' ')

    areaprice_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="listings-container"]/div['+ str(q) +']/div[1]/div[2]/ul[2]/li[3]')
    if areaprice_element is not None:
        for x in areaprice_element:
            areaprice.append(x.text)
    else:
        areaprice.append(' ')
```

Comment: too fast bro :) I hope you will get reward  for this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. i checked and it still doesn't  show the empty value on [div13]
Result:
[['96 m²', '120 m²'], ['Rp 18.055.556 per m²']]

Expected:
[['96 m²', '120 m²'], [ ,'Rp 18.055.556 per m²']]

Thank you

Comment: From you comment I understand you are expecting `,` not the empty space. Correct? Also, can you present me some example of result where all the elements are presented?

Comment: Hi @Prophet, thanks for asking.
I'm expecting the code to create empty value to fill in the first element of 'areaprice' which is not present [div13]. 

If we use same code and set 'q' increment in range (14,16), then the code works as expected, i.e. [['170 m²', '84 m²'], ['Rp 14.285.714 per m²', 'Rp 7.058.824 per m²']].

Comment: You asked to assign an empty value instead of `None` in case the element doesn't exist and this is what I did here. So, if your list of strings contains 2 strings it appears `['str1','str2']` and when there is only 1 string there it will appear as `['str2']`, not `[,'str2']`. But if you still have to fill something in place of missing text it will be not an empty string but some string like `' '`. In this case it will be `[' ','str2']`. I currently see no alternative. But maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes. thats what i mean, to fill something in place of the missing text. sorry if i make this confusing. the intention is to put some string ('  ') like you said to retain two elements on each. appreciate if somebody has some thought how to fill this missing string. thanks for clarifying, anyway.

Comment: It's very simple. Just use `' '` instead of `""` as were in the initial solution. I will add that shortly

Comment: hi. i have tried to just using ' ' , but the outcome still doesn't recognize as expected. this is the outcome from my end on [area, areaprice].
[['96 m²', '120 m²'], ['Rp 18.055.556 per m²']]
Note: dunno why have to set 'q in range (12,14)' to get this anomaly.

Comment: No! not `''` but `' '` , there is a space between the apostrophes!

Comment: yes. i did it with space '  '. you can check the revised code run above (↑).